# PHP string literals file...good practice?

Tags: php, string

I've been trying to create a string literals file for PHP, so I can hold all of my strings in one file.

I was wondering if it was good practice to do something like:

```
class Literals
{
    const String1 = "Hello";
    const String2 = "World!";
    //... (up to 100+ literals)...
}
```

And then somewhere in my code I could call it like:

```
$hello = Literals::String1;
```

Is this good practice?

Comment: That's not much different from plain old text constants, except you have a more cumbersome syntax. Is the purpose to later translate those strings? (If so: avoid. Use gettext or any solution without mnemonic string ids.)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you're going to do with the strings. If you're going to display them to the user, then sure, it's a simple way of doing internationalization, although you'll want to look at something more advanced if you're going to do a lot of it. If you're just going to use them for associative array keys, database column names or other internal things, then no, just keep them inline.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you did not really call them String1...StringN :)

If for localization I **personally** would prefer this one (as used by Apple):

In code use something like:

```
<h1><?php localize("Homepage","String for the homepage") ?></h1>
```

.

```
function localize($key,$help='') {
   //do a lookup of the key and if not found use the key itself
}
```

Then you can use a parser to find all strings and create a reference translation:

```
$strings = array(
 /** String for the homepage */
 'Homepage' => 'Homepage'
);
```

This has the advantage that the main language version will always work and other translations can be added when needed.
It's disadvantage is that you need a parser to find all strings.

Comment: i have done similar things, but always call the function name something shorter because i get sick of typing it. eg l($key, $help='');  it is also nice to have a way to force it to show errors if a key is missing instead of always defaulting to the key itself, as sometimes a small typo can cause text not to be translated, and it is not that easy to pickup the mistake